# How to keep duplicated rownames in melt process?

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I am trying to draw grouped boxplot in R. Data is like:

```
mydf <- structure(list(Category = c("RPP", "RR"), P10 = c(3.352174769, 
    3.539193849), P2 = c(0, 3.090577955), P10 = c(3.273878984, 3.160004973
    ), P2 = c(0, 3.159418605), P10 = c(3.182712494, 3.316038858), 
        P2 = c(0L, 0L), P10 = c(2.770653831, 3.293476876), P2 = c(2.635533787, 
        3.245297416), P10 = c(0, 3.924497418), P2 = c(0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Category", 
    "P10", "P2", "P10", "P2", "P10", "P2", "P10", "P2", "P10", "P2"
    ), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")


mydf
##   Category      P10       P2      P10       P2      P10 P2      P10       P2      P10 P2
## 1      RPP 3.352175 0.000000 3.273879 0.000000 3.182712  0 2.770654 2.635534 0.000000  0
## 2       RR 3.539194 3.090578 3.160005 3.159419 3.316039  0 3.293477 3.245297 3.924497  0
```

In which I would like to generate a dataframe like below for plotting in ggplot2:

- Category    variable   values
- RPP         P10    3.35
- RPP         P2     0
- RR          P10    3.54
- ...

How ever, after using melt() function:

```
melt(test, "Category")
```

I found only the first two columns are kept in the data, which means the following duplicate columns are miss cause they have same column names.
Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `melt` from "data.table", you won't have that problem:

```
library(data.table)
melt(as.data.table(mydf), "Category")
#     Category variable    value
#  1:      RPP      P10 3.352175
#  2:       RR      P10 3.539194
#  3:      RPP       P2 0.000000
#  4:       RR       P2 3.090578
#  5:      RPP      P10 3.273879
#  6:       RR      P10 3.160005
#  7:      RPP       P2 0.000000
#  8:       RR       P2 3.159419
#  9:      RPP      P10 3.182712
# 10:       RR      P10 3.316039
# 11:      RPP       P2 0.000000
# 12:       RR       P2 0.000000
# 13:      RPP      P10 2.770654
# 14:       RR      P10 3.293477
# 15:      RPP       P2 2.635534
# 16:       RR       P2 3.245297
# 17:      RPP      P10 0.000000
# 18:       RR      P10 3.924497
# 19:      RPP       P2 0.000000
# 20:       RR       P2 0.000000
```

---

A base R alternative is to use `stack`, like this:

```
cbind(Category = mydf[[1]], stack(mydf[-1]))
##    Category   values   ind
## 1       RPP 3.352175   P10
## 2        RR 3.539194   P10
## 3       RPP 0.000000    P2
## 4        RR 3.090578    P2
## 5       RPP 3.273879 P10.1
## 6        RR 3.160005 P10.1
## 7       RPP 0.000000  P2.1
## 8        RR 3.159419  P2.1
## 9       RPP 3.182712 P10.2
## 10       RR 3.316039 P10.2
## 11      RPP 0.000000  P2.2
## 12       RR 0.000000  P2.2
## 13      RPP 2.770654 P10.3
## 14       RR 3.293477 P10.3
## 15      RPP 2.635534  P2.3
## 16       RR 3.245297  P2.3
## 17      RPP 0.000000 P10.4
## 18       RR 3.924497 P10.4
## 19      RPP 0.000000  P2.4
## 20       RR 0.000000  P2.4
```

Depending on how you plan to use the data, you may then need to also clean up the "ind" column.

---

Sample data:

```
mydf <- structure(list(Category = c("RPP", "RR"), P10 = c(3.352174769, 
    3.539193849), P2 = c(0, 3.090577955), P10 = c(3.273878984, 3.160004973
    ), P2 = c(0, 3.159418605), P10 = c(3.182712494, 3.316038858), 
        P2 = c(0L, 0L), P10 = c(2.770653831, 3.293476876), P2 = c(2.635533787, 
        3.245297416), P10 = c(0, 3.924497418), P2 = c(0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Category", 
    "P10", "P2", "P10", "P2", "P10", "P2", "P10", "P2", "P10", "P2"
    ), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case that you do some transformations as well and need to go back to the initial representation at some point, it is good to have this option by still having the groups you need:

```
mydf %>% 
    setNames(nm = make.unique(names(.))) %>% 
    reshape2::melt("Category") %>% 
    transform(group = sub(x = variable, pattern = "\\.\\d+$", replacement = ""))
```

But @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1's suggestion is of course way shorter and I have to keep that one in mind... did not know that `data.table` can handle this.